# Slow Query Execution In SQL Server Due to Partitions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, query-optimization, database-partitioning

I have the following query in SQL Server 2012:

```
SELECT
    Code
    , ReferenceKey
    , CodeKey
FROM dbo.Codes
WHERE
    PartitionKey = 'PART1'
    AND CurrentPosition = 1
    AND Deleted = 0
    AND Code = 'CODE1'
    AND ReferenceKey = 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

This gives the following statistics output:

```
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

(1 row(s) affected)
Table 'Codes'. Scan count 239, logical reads 10, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

(1 row(s) affected)

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 31 ms,  elapsed time = 35 ms.
```

The actual execution plan shows a single index seek against an index defined as:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [idx_Codes] ON [dbo].[Codes]
(
    [PartitionKey] ASC,
    [Code] ASC,
    [ReferenceKey] ASC,
    [CurrentPosition] ASC,
    [Deleted] ASC
)
INCLUDE ([CodeKey]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
```

If I rephrase the query to:

```
SELECT
    Code
    , ReferenceKey
    , CodeKey
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            Code
            , ReferenceKey
            , CodeKey
        FROM dbo.Codes
        WHERE
            PartitionKey = 'PART1'
            AND CurrentPosition = 1
            AND Deleted = 0
            AND Code = 'CODE1'
            AND ReferenceKey = 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    ) Q
```

I get the following statistics output, which shows a significant reduction in both CPU time and elapsed time:

```
(1 row(s) affected)
Table 'Codes'. Scan count 1, logical reads 3, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

(1 row(s) affected)

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 1 ms.
```

The execution plan is identical, other than the latter includes a more elaborate Seek Predicate which appears to mean that the query is targeting only 1 of 239 partitions.

Actual execution plan XML extract for the first query:

```
<RunTimePartitionSummary>
  <PartitionsAccessed PartitionCount="239">
    <PartitionRange Start="1" End="239" />
  </PartitionsAccessed>
</RunTimePartitionSummary>
```

And for the second query:

```
<RunTimePartitionSummary>
  <PartitionsAccessed PartitionCount="1">
    <PartitionRange Start="14" End="14" />
  </PartitionsAccessed>
</RunTimePartitionSummary>
```

The partition key is based only on the column `PartitionKey`.

Why are these queries interpreted so differently (particularly in terms of how they perform) by the query optimizer?

Also, currently, only 2 or 3 of the 239 partitions have any data in them, so I'm wondering what might account for the significant difference in performance between the two queries?

One further thing to add is that after restarting the SQL Server service, this problem appears to resolve itself, with the execution times both going down to 0-2 milliseconds, however, the variation in execution plans/Seek Predicates is still the same.

**Paste The Plan Links**

First query: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HyfFHXeJF

First query after SQL Server service restart: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BkWk-EeyY

(The first query is much quicker after a restart, and the only difference in the actual execution plan is that the `StmtSimple` node's value for the `StatementCompId` attribute has changed from 2 to 0.)

Second query: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HkIeEQlyK

Comment: Empty partitions still need to be seeked into and this can add appreciable overhead if you don't get partition elimination https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/268647/3690

Comment: What is the original seek predicate and the "more elaborate Seek Predicate"?

Comment: Also does the first execution plan show signs of auto parameterisation? In fact can you just post both plans to https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?

Comment: @MartinSmith - I've added Paste The Plan links for the actual execution plans.

Comment: The first query is auto parameterised. This means SQL Server is unable to simplify at compile time using the passed in values as it needs to create a plan that works for any parameter value. Wrapping in the derived table prevents the auto parameterisation and it compiles a plan for the literals and can detect at compile time it only needs to go to partition 14. As for why the parameterised plan does not do parameter elimination at run time here and just produces a plan that accesses all partitions I'm not sure without testing.

Comment: Maybe optimisation of this was just bad in 2012. Or maybe it is due to mismatch between the inferred parameter data type and the actual column data type (I see an implicit cast to nvarchar(4000)) or maybe it just was cheap enough it never investigated that in optimisation (stopped at trivial plan stage)

Comment: "parameter elimination" above should be "partition elimination" of course

Comment: @MartinSmith - Thanks for your analysis. Do you have any idea as to why restarting the SQL Server service would significantly improve this query? I've added another Paste The Plan for the first query after a restart, where the only difference seems to be that `StatementCompId` has changed from 2 to 0.

Comment: Have you tried appending `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` to the offending queries?  Restarting your server speeds up your query: that suggests that a newly compiled query, with a purpose-built execution plan, might be better at partition elimination.